# Does YALMIP allow a user-defined function for the objective function and constraints?

Tags: robust-optimization, yalmip

I have a robust optimization problem where the decision variable is a matrix, and the uncertain parameter is a vector.  My matrix is `L`, and the uncertain parameter is `x` in the problem below:

```
clear all;
sdpvar L(2,2) x(2,1); 
y = 4*x(2) + 3 + L(1,1) + L(2,1)*x(1) + L(2,2)*x(2); % objective function 
F = [0 <= 3 +2*x(2) + 4 + L(1,1)*x(2)]; % constraints 
F = [F, 0 <= L(1,1), 0 <= L(2,1)]; % constraints 
U = [0 <= x(1), x(2) <= 1, 0 <= x(2) , uncertain(x)]; % uncertainty description 
options = sdpsettings('solver', 'bmibnb'); 
result = optimize(F + U, y, options);
```

The above problem is similar in structure to the problem I want to solve.  However, the scale of my problem is much larger.  This makes it very inconvenient to define the objective function and constraints in the way shown above.  So, I’d like to be able to define my objective function and constraints by passing the work to another function, which takes as input the matrix `L` and vector `x` as one might expect.  For example:

```
function [result] = y(x, L)                                                  
  result= 4*x(2) + 3 + L(1,1) + L(2,1)*x(1) + L(2,2)*x(2);
end
```

One can imagine that this would allow things like `for` loops, and other conveniences.  Knowing that my objective function and constraints are linear in `L` and `x`, I’m aware that there exist matrices that would also allow me to express the objective function in the simple example shown above.  But I’d rather not go through that if it isn’t necessary.

Does YALMIP allow a user-defined function as shown above?  Or must it be expressed in one line as shown in my example?

Comment: You might get a faster answer at https://groups.google.com/g/yalmip .

Comment: Thanks.  I posted it [there](https://groups.google.com/g/yalmip/c/ZvR9DCQ3hok) as well, although I prefer the feature of SE that allows you to edit after posting, to make the question more readable to others.

Comment: If you want to be able to edit questions, use the discussions at the github repository for YALMIP. Questions like these are better asked at dedicated sites (question answered in the groups site)

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Didn't know there was a discussion at the github repo.  Sorry for creating more work for you @JohanLöfberg!  After the question is answered there, I'll copy the answer here and answer my own question (unless you'd like to do that).